# How to update multiple rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have importing table in my database. This table columns are `product_id` and `ext_product_id`. `Product_id` is unique, but `ext_product_id` in table has same. I have to update this multiple `ext_product_id`. My table has thousands of columns. I can't manualy update these rows.

my table foramt is:

```
    product_id     ext_product_id
      44            796666
      45            796666
      46            796666
      306           1275631
      308           1275631
      309           1275631 
       .             .
```

i have table foramt like this:

```
    my table foramt is:

    product_id     ext_product_id
      44            796666
      45            796667
      46            796668
      306           1275631
      308           1275632
      309           1275633 
       .             .
```

How to update this ?

My query only works with a single record:

```
   update 13_product_id 
   set ext_product_id='796667'
   where product_id='45';
```

I have to update multiple rows, please give me a suggestion.

Comment: well, I see only one row with `product_id='45'`

Comment: update 13_product_id 
   set ext_product_id='796668'
   where product_id='46';

Comment: how to update multiple row @Notulysses

Comment: Then remove `WHERE` clause, if you want to update all records. If you want to updated only some rows ,then list them in the `IN` clause.

Comment: Do you have many different 'product_id' entries in the '13_product_id' table that need to be updated from your imported table?

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Try updating where your IDs are in:

```
 update 13_product_id 
   set ext_product_id='796666'
   where product_id in ('45','16','15');
```

etc, etc

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on what you want to do you can add multiple ids into the loop so instead of

```
where product_id = 45
```

You could have

```
where product_id in (45,46,47,48)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the product_id's to update, use **IN** like this:

```
update product_id 
set ext_product_id='796666'
where product_id IN (45, 46, 386...);
```

Or, if you want to update **all rows** with that ext_product_id, just drop your "where" clause::

```
update product_id 
set ext_product_id='796666'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update all rows that have the same extended product as `'45'`?  If so, this should do what you want:

```
update 13_product_id toupdate join
       (select ext_product_id
        from 13_product_id
        where product_id = '45'
       ) t
       on toupdate.ext_product_id = t.ext_product_id
   set toupdate.ext_product_id = '796667';
```